# Passing colormap to scatter3

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is basic but I'm struggling to give `scatter3` a colormap. I'm doing this:

```
scatter3(gesture_x(:,1),gesture_x(:,2),gesture_x(:,3),1,colors(labels_x))
```

Where `colors = ['c','y','m'...]` and `labels_x = [1 3 3 2 ..]`

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the single-character color specifications to specify an array of colors to be used for each point. MATLAB will actually interpret `['c', 'y', 'm']` as `'cym'` and that isn't a valid color so it is going to error out.

If you look at [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#inputarg_C), you need to specify the color in one of three ways:

- RGB values for each data point (an `N x 3` array where the columns are red, green, and blue components),
- A single color (`'r'` or `'red'` or `[1 0 0]`) to be applied to *all* points,
- A number which will be mapped to the colormap of the axes using the `clims`.

> Marker color, specified as a color string, an RGB row vector, a three-column matrix of RGB values, or a vector. For an RGB row vector, use a three-element row vector whose elements specify the intensities of the red, green, and blue components of the color. The intensities must be in the range [0 1]. If you have three points in the scatter plot and want the colors to be indices into the colormap, specify C as a three-element column vector.

```
% Random RGB value for each point
colors = rand(size(gesture_x, 1), 3);

% One color for everything
colors = 'r';
colors = 'red';
colors = [1 0 0];

% Random values mapped to the axes colormap
colors = rand(size(gesture_x,1), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer complements the excellent existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790404/8239061) with a full example and uses information gained from the answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54675647/8239061).

I find the easiest way to apply color using [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) is through the [`colormap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C) draws each circle with the color specified by C.
>
> If C is a RGB triplet or character vector or string containing a color
>   name, then all circles are plotted with the specified color.
>
> If C is a three column matrix with the number of rows in C equal to
>   the length of X, Y, and Z, then each row of C specifies an RGB color
>   value for the corresponding circle.
>
> **If C is a vector with length equal to the length of X, Y, and Z, then**
>   **the values in C are linearly mapped to the colors in the current**
>   **colormap.**

Full example provided below with customization (except for marker size control). 
[image: 3D scatter plot with colormap]

```
% MATLAB R2017a 
% Data
NumPoints = 25;
X = 100*rand(NumPoints,1);
Y = 100*rand(NumPoints,1);
Z = 100*rand(NumPoints,1);
V = (X + Y);

% Create custom colormap     (2 color example)
col1 = [0 1 0]; %G
col2 = [1 0 0]; %R
cmap = interp1([col1; col2], linspace(1, 2, 101)); % Create the colormap

% Plot
colormap(cmap), hold on, box on
h = scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],V,'filled')
view(-25,25)   % (azimuth,elevation)

% Colorbar Controls
cb = colorbar;
caxis([0 200])    % sets min and max value for color mapping (separate from tick control)
cb.Limits = [0 200];
cb.Ticks = [0:25:200];  % custom set colorbar ticks
cb.Label.String = ' V';
cb.Label.Rotation = 0;   % Default is 90

% Cosmetics
h.MarkerEdgeColor = 'k';     % Set marker edge color to black
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
```