# Creating a colormap in Matlab with 30 colors

Tags: matlab, matrix, colormap

I am having trouble writing a script that will show shades of green and blue. A colormap needs to be created that has 30 colors (10 blue, 10 aqua, 10 green). In the image the blues will be in the first row, aquas in the second, and green in the third. I am using Matlab and I shouldn't use loops.

```
colors = [0.2 0.1 0.5; 0.1 .5 0.8; 0.2 0.7 0.6; 0.8 0.7 0.3; 0.9 1 0];
colormap(winter)
vec = 1:length(colors);
image(vec)
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806345/how-do-i-create-a-colormap-with-shades-of-blue-and-gree

Comment: I have updated it with the code I have thus far. Right now, I have all shades of blue, no aqua, no green, and only 5 colors.

Comment: Does the **Bonus** section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676842/8239061)  using [`interp1()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) by @gnovice answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

%this script will show shades of green and blue

colors = zeros(3,10,3);

colors(:,:,3) = [.1:.1:1;.1:.1:1; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

colors(:,:,2) = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;.1:.1:1;.1:.1:1];

image(colors)